# How to disable the arrow up and down event on MUI Menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In my menu I have a text field and a button. The text field type is number type. So when I click on the text field and click the arrow up and down, I want it to value to increase and decrease. But instead of that happening, it's selecting the menu items. This is the code.

```
<Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        PaperProps={{
          elevation: 0,
          sx: {
            overflow: "visible",
            filter: "drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))",
            mt: 1.5,
            "& .MuiAvatar-root": {
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              ml: -0.5,
              mr: 1,
            },
            "&:before": {
              content: '""',
              display: "block",
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              right: 14,
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              bgcolor: "background.paper",
              transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)",
              zIndex: 0,
            },
          },
        }}
        transformOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "top" }}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "bottom" }}
      >
        <MenuItem>
          <TextField
            label="Quantity"
            type="number"
            InputProps={{
              inputProps: { min: "0", step: "1" },
            }}
            size="small"
            sx={{ width: "120px" }}
            value={editingItem.quantity}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setEditingItem({ ...editingItem, quantity: e.target.value })
            }
          />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="small"
            onClick={updateItem}
            fullWidth
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
```

I tried wrapping the menu items in `<MenuList/>` and used the option `autoFocusItem={false}` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also investigated ways to disable the behavior of the arrow keys on MUI's `<Menu>` and `<MenuList>` components, but concluded that there are no MUI props or other methods to disable the behavior. Instead, what I did was replace `<MenuList>` with a regular `<List>`. The props for `<List>` and its functionality are very similar to `<Menu>`.  Hopefully, all you'll need to do is use the List component.